# Which interface/abstract class is for grails Domain class behaviour?

Tags: grails

I have a generic method for doing a common operation on many domain class

```
static Map getNumberOfPropertyByTopicIds(def criteriaClass, List ids) {
  criteriaClass.createCriteria(). //Some GORM methods used
}
```

I wanted autocomplete on various things applied on `criteriaClass`. But for doing that I need to replace `def criteriaClass` to `InterfaceForDomainClassBehaviour criteriaClass`.

But I don't know `InterfaceForDomainClassBehaviour` is what. Which interface/abstract class implements Domain class behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't one.

Grails uses "convention over configuration", so unlike other frameworks where you extend a base class, implement one or more interfaces, use annotations, etc., you simply put your artifact classes (domain classes, services, etc.) in the correct directory under `grails-app`, use the appropriate class naming convention (except for domain classes), and Grails mixes in behavior for you. You can configure things of course, e.g. with the `mapping` block, etc.

Before Grails 2 adding methods was mostly done using Groovy runtime metaprogramming, and in Grails 2 most of the behavior is added at compile time using ASTs, and runtime metaprogramming is used mostly for dynamic code like `findAllByHeightAndWeightAndHairColorAndShoeSize` where it would be impractical and/or impossible to compile in every combination.

Over 100 methods are added to domain classes (decompile some - it's pretty amazing to see how much ends up in your classes considering how small the Groovy source is) and dozens are added to controllers. But this is all mixed in, so although there is significant overlap between your domain classes, there's no common base class or interface unless you add them yourself.

Comment: So basically every domain class is a `mixin` of multiple classes + runtime metaprogramming.